# sed(1): prepend a line

Tags: shell, scripting, sed

I have the following text structure inside a file:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*"
},
```

I would like to add

> , "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*"

before '},' using sed(1).

I also have to take into consideration that the last line might and might not have a comma at the end.

I tried alot of things;

```
sed '/require/,/\},/ { /[^,]$/ i//&,\n        '\'something\''/ }' composer.json;
```

but I can't get it to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to use sed? It might be safer in general to decode the JSON, add in the key and re-encode it (using PHP, for instance).

Comment: Perhaps using a PHP script would be easier to do this? My main objective is to call some kind of a script to edit this file (add a JSON element).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is difficult to accomplish robustly with sed, you should rather use a proper JSON library.

But to do what you want with GNU sed you can do something like this (here without checking for ending comma):

```
sed '/require/,/},/ s/},/, "friendsofsymfony\/user-bundle": "\*"\n&/
```

To check for an ending comma, you need to do some more parsing:

*parse.sed*

```
/^[ \t]*"require/ {                       # when 'require' found
  : a
  N                                       # run through pairwise
  /\n[\t ]*\},/! { P; s/[^\n]+\n//; ba }  # lines until '},' is found
  /,\n/! s/\n/,&/                         # append comma if not present
  s/\n([\t ]*)},/\n\1\1"friendsofsymfony\/user-bundle": "\*"&/
}
```

Run with:

```
sed -rf parse.sed infile
```

Excerpt of output of *parse.sed* when run on the provided example file:

```
[...]

"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.0.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*"
},

[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `i` command to insert. Newline is needed at the end of the string to be inserted:

```
sed '/require/,/},/{/^},/i, "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*"
}'
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Try it on this file: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/composer.json

Comment: @Tool: You have to include the indentation: `/require/,/},/{/^ *},/i`

Comment: Some implementations of sed require a newline after the `i`.